# executeFetchRequest returns entities from different NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, executefetchrequest

In my app I use two `NSManagedObjectContexts`, one to store permanent data, the other one just for handling temporary data (so I can work with the `NSManagedObject` subclasses).

When I execute a fetch request after I created a temporary entity in my temporary `NSManagedObjectContext`, I get all permanently stored entities AND the temporary entities.

Here is my code:

```
//create temporarily stored entity
Entity *entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:temporaryManagedObjectContext];

//...

//get permanently stored entities
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[[permanentManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error&error] mutableCopy];
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How is the temporary context created? Is it saved after inserting the new object?

Comment: It's created using the same NSPersistentStoreCoordinator as the permanent context and it's never saved.

Comment: That is strange, and I cannot reproduce the behaviour in a short test program.

Comment: Can you isolate this activity in a test case?

Comment: And can you please add the code that creates the temporary context, in case there's anything useful in it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, your comments lead me to my error, very stupid I have to say: I copied the code for the creation of the temporary context from the permanent context and forgot to replace all occurances, shame on me!

```
if (temporaryManagedObjectContext != nil) return temporaryManagedObjectContext;

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    temporaryManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [temporaryManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}

//returned the wrong NSManagedObjectContext
return permanentManagedObjectContext;
```